# Google Translate API Issue

Tags: .net

I am trying to translate a simple string using Google Translate API. Although I have not setup billing now but I have my API Key to accomplish this.

It is giving an error/exception:

```
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Daily Limit Exceeded [403]
Errors [
    Message[Daily Limit Exceeded] Location[ - ] Reason[dailyLimitExceeded] Domain[usageLimits]
]
```

Please let me know how can I overcome this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According documentation, It seems that API in particular can't be used without paying a fee

```
Translate API -> Courtesy limit: 0 characters/day
```

Other APIs allow a limeted amount of free requests but it's not the case of google translation.

You can verify this on your google api console.

Answer (score 1):

API key needs to be purchased for Google but Microsoft (Bing Translator) still provides free API calls for translation. Google also provides offline translation as well - by uploading the sheet containing the data to be translated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to purchase an API key. Both, Google and Microsoft (Bing Translator) now charge money (you have a certain number of translations free, though).

- To use Google Translator, you have to purchase a license from Google.
  [Follow the steps described by Google.](http://code.google.com/intl/de/apis/language/translate/v2/pricing.html)
- To use Microsoft Bing Translator, you have to purchase a license from Microsoft.
  [Follow the steps described by Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh454950.aspx).